# ‘removeNaNFromPointCloud’ is not a member of ‘pcl’

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When I try to do rosmake on my package I get the following error:

```
‘removeNaNFromPointCloud’ is not a member of ‘pcl’
```

However I can see it in the documentation: [here](http://docs.pointclouds.org/trunk/filter_8hpp_source.html#l00045)

Code:

```
void cloud_cb (sensor_msgs::PointCloud2 input) {
  pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ> in_cloud;
  pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ> out_cloud;
  std::vector<int> indicies;
  pcl::fromROSMsg(input, in_cloud);
  pcl::fromROSMsg(input, out_cloud);
  pcl::removeNaNFromPointCloud(in_cloud, out_cloud, indicies);
}
```

Anyone know why this is currently saying it's not part of the pcl?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/45763/%E2%80%98removenanfrompointcloud%E2%80%99-is-not-a-member-of-%E2%80%98pcl%E2%80%99/) by [Muadibz](https://answers.ros.org/users/3374/muadibz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2012-10-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have you included this?:

```
#include <pcl/filters/filter.h>
```

---

Originally posted by [Martin Peris](https://answers.ros.org/users/1108/martin-peris/) with karma: 5625 on 2012-10-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6